# How to change or conversion utf8_general_ci to binary in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, character-encoding, mediawiki, collation

When I tested the new version (1.20wmf4) of MediaWiki I saw (see: [screen capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCSkq.png)) the following message about database character set:

> In **binary mode**, MediaWiki stores UTF-8 text to the database in binary fields. **This is more efficient than MySQL's UTF-8 mode**, and allows you to use the full range of Unicode characters.
>
> In **UTF-8 mode**, MySQL will know what character set your data is in, and can present and convert it appropriately, but it will not let you store characters above the Basic Multilingual Plane.

I've my own Wiki on the MediaWiki engine, but my tables are with `utf8_general_ci` collation. My question is: **how to easily change the collation from `utf8_general_ci` to `binary` in an existing database?**

My MediaWiki version: 1.19.0
My MySQL info:

- Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
- Server version: 5.1.52
- Protocol version: 10
- MySQL charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)

Answer (score 2):

I had to do something similar not too long ago and followed the instructions here: http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Backing_up_a_wiki#Latin-1_to_UTF-8_conversion. You basically have to export the database, replace `utf8_general_ci` with `binary` in the exported SQL, and then import the database again. The sed line in those instructions wasn't quite right but you can also manually edit your dumped SQL file and fix any instances of `utf8_general_ci`.